# VueJs: How to pass current iterated item to dialog?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and v-list.

My target is delete user after dialog.
But I didn't know what is the best way to pass item to dialog.

My aim is pass current iterated item as arguments like below.

Here is my code snip.

```
<v-btn 
color="green 
darken-1" 
flat 
@click="deleteUser(user.name)">Yes
</v-btn>
```

https://codepen.io/98mprice/pen/xaQKXZ?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define method `deleteUser(user)` on Vue instance and use `splice` method to remove an item from an array at the specific index position.

You pass `user` variable just by reference its name inside v-for in view template.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPJjOd) you have your codepen which was edited to support deletion once you clicked on an item.

PS. Consider adding unique `id` for each `user` and then perform an action passing only `id`, not an entire `user` object.

Edit:

I suggest to use third-party lib like [vuejs-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-dialog) to show an alert before a user deletion. Configuring the library is pretty simple, just follow README.

Then your `deleteUser` method might look like this:

```
deleteUser(user) {
   this.$dialog.confirm('Do you want to delete a user?')
    .then(dialog => {
        console.log('Clicked on proceed')
        const index = this.users.indexOf(user);      
        this.users.splice(index, 1); 
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('Clicked on cancel')
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  But I want to confirm before delete not as you code is delete immediately.   How can delete after confirm dialog?

Comment: Edited my answer. Follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-dialog for details please.